# SSH How to scrutinise what a PID is doing?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, pid, centos6

I have a rogue Apache process running on a Centos 6 Linux server, which is running up to 55% CPU and wondered how I can scrutinise exactly what function(s) it is performing?  From the 'top' command I have its process ID, but how can I drill in to what it's up to?

Thank you

Comment: You can `ps -ef | grep <PID>` to get some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for that.  This confirms that it relates to usr/sbin/httpd (so Apache then), but doesn't offer any further drill down.  Is there a way to know what scripts it is running, from which domain folder etc?

Comment: Mmm I don't really know. Maybe you could check the connections entering, but I am not very familiar to that. In [su] they might help you better, as it is a more related topic for this quesiton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to see what it's doing, get familiar with the strace command.  It will show you the system calls your process is making, but I imagine it would be a terrible tool for finding out performance issues.  For that, take a look at something like gprof.

Comment: that will only be useful if it does syscalls (instead of just running local code (e.g. infinite loop)), but that's a reasonable assumption.